# In Java, when catching an exception, returning to for loop

Tags: java, exception, loops

Is it possible to return to a loop if an exception is thrown?

Lets say my code is:

```
try {
     for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
          sysout(a[i])
     } 
} catch (Exception e) {
     sysout("Error")
}
```

And I want to the loop to resume where it stopped.

Comment: Why don't you put the try/catch **inside** the loop?

Answer (score 12):

this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    try {
        sysout(a[i]);
    } catch (Exception e)  {
        sysout("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
```

Use

```
for(int i = startIndex; i<a.length; i++)
```

and you can guess you need to initialize startIndex to 0 and set it to the loop value on exception so the next time you enter the loop it starts at startIndex.